# Airflow ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'

Tags: python, azure, airflow

I'm trying to create my own custom hook and operator for Airflow, but get the following error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/test_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/test_dag.py", line 9, in <module>
    from plugins.operators.synapse import AzureSynapseRunPipelineOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
my-git-repo/
├── dags/
│   ├── test_dag.py
├── plugins/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── hooks/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── synapse.py
│   ├── operators/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── synapse.py (contains AzureSynapseRunPipelineOperator)
```

In test_dag.py, I'm doing the following import:

```
 from plugins.operators.synapse import AzureSynapseRunPipelineOperator
```

I'm currently testing these changes using a Docker image of Airflow. However, I get a similar error when I do a git sync of my test dag to an Azure Managed Instance of Airflow.

Airflow version: 2.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [best practices for module loading](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/modules_management.html#best-practices-for-module-loading).

`plugins` is (by default) a folder added to PYTHONPATH making it a base when searching for modules. "plugins" itself is then not a module name.

With your structure you should use:

```
 from operators.synapse import AzureSynapseRunPipelineOperator
```